# python join,map and lambda methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I am quite new to python. Can someone explain this line

```
exec("print(' '.join(map(lambda x: s[x::{0}], range({0}))))".format(ceil(sqrt(len(s)))))
```

What does `s[x::{0}]` and `range({0}))` mean ?

in below piece of code in detail?

This code is a solution for below hackerrank question :
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/encryption/problem

```
#!/bin/python3

import sys
from math import ceil, floor, sqrt


def encryption(s):
    exec("print(' '.join(map(lambda x: s[x::{0}], range({0}))))".format(ceil(sqrt(len(s)))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = input().strip()
    result = encryption(s)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simplified version of your code, which you should be able to follow:

```
from math import ceil, sqrt

s = 'hello'

y = ceil(sqrt(len(s)))
# 3

res = ' '.join(map(lambda x: s[x::y], range(y)))
# 'hl eo l'
```

**Essential points**

- `y` is the rounded-up square root of the length of `s`, in this case sqrt(5) is rounded up to 3.
- `lambda` is an anonymous function which maps each value in `range(y)`, i.e. `0, 1, 2` is mapped to `s[x::y]`, i.e. return every `y`th element of sequence beginning from index `x`. See also [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation). `x` is arbitrary notation for a member of `range(y)`.
- Join all resulting values with a space to form a single string.
- In your original code `{0}` and `str.format` are used to incorporate `y` in your string in one line. In this case, I consider it convoluted and bad practice.

Comment: what does x stand for here?
Each value in range(y), i.e. 0, 1, 2 is mapped to s[x::y], i.e. return every yth element of sequence beginning from index x.  how lambda function mapping takes place in this casE?

Comment: Sorry I understood now, it is like for each element of the list, iterate from current element (x) to range(y). so first iteration will produce hel, 2nd will produce lo. when we do " ".join(hel,lo), it will produce "hl eo l"

Answer (score 1):

This line is using the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) function on a string.
Thus, the `{0}` will be replaced by the first element in the format function which is `ceil(sqrt(len(s))))`

Answer (score 1):

When using the str.format() method ([see here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)), the brackets and characters in them will be replaced with the objects passed in the method. The "0" indicates replacement with the first character passed in the method.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documetnation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) you can see what `format()` does.

In your example:

```
exec("print(' '.join(map(lambda x: s[x::{0}], range({0}))))".format(ceil(sqrt(len(s)))))
```

You are inserting the result of `ceil(sqrt(len(s)))` in two places, namely:

```
lambda x: s[x::ceil(sqrt(len(s)))]
```

and

```
range(ceil(sqrt(len(s))))
```

Now, `exec` could be avoided here with simple variable:

```
def encryption(s):
    var = ceil(sqrt(len(s)))
    print(' '.join(map(lambda x: s[x::var], range(var))))
```